# Angularjs: Compile ng-repeat dynamically

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have found some strange behavior with Angularjs. My directive simply adds and compiles `ng-repeat` to my dom element. However the scope variable `item` is not accessible. Look at the code below for explanation.

```js
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('customRepeat', function($compile) {
    return {
      priority: 2000,
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function(element){
        element.attr('ng-repeat', 'item in [1,2,3,4,5,6]')
          
        return function(scope, element) {
          $compile(element)(scope)
        }
      }
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app='demo'>
    <h3>My Items</h3>
    <div custom-repeat>
      Item: {{item}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Who has some Angularjs skills to figure this one out?

N.B. Try and run this with an older version of Angularjs (say 1.2.x) and you will see that it works as intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct way to compile directive when raw DOM is modified is, create `compileFn` from directive compile function like `var compileFn = $compile(element)` and then inside link function recompile element with liked `scope`. That way you will also see `Maximum call stack exceed error` in both Angular 1.2.X & 1.6.X version. Check [**this plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/GPoLn4UmnZWIMf2BrR5a?p=preview) by opening console.

Basically what happening is, you are adding an `ng-repeat` on directive element & recompiling that element once again which will lead to compilation of `customDirective` once again, and this process will keep on happening infinitely. So before compiling element once again, you should make sure that you had removed `custom-report` directive attribute. That will not allowed to `custom-report` infinite execution.

```
var demo = angular.module('demo', []);
demo.directive('customRepeat', function($compile) {
    return {
      priority: 2000,
      restrict: 'A',
      compile: function(element){
        element.attr('ng-repeat', 'item in [1,2,3,4,5,6]')
        element.removeAttr('custom-repeat');
        //this line is need for compilation of element
        var compile = $compile(element);
        return function(scope, element) {
          compile(scope); //linking scope
        }
      }
    }
});
```

[**Plunker Demo**](http://plnkr.co/edit/qmmj6BzOhZUxZu4dAGU8?p=preview)

Comment: Maybe I wasn't clear. If you run the code you will see that the `{{item}}` is not getting bound. It should say `Item 1`, `Item 2`... and so on. It does not throw any kind of error.

Comment: The strangest thing is, as I just noticed, by adding an empty expression `{{}}` after `{{item}}` actually fixes the issue momentarily. It surely seems like a bug.

Comment: @Tympanix check my updated answer with plunker demo.. hope its clear now..

Comment: I see now. Very clever solution. The `Maximum call stack exceed error` is not getting thrown in JSFiddle which is why I was confused. Thank you